# how does the machine handle the multithreaded applications

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, request, host

I hope this will not be the stupidest question ever.

let's imagine that we have a web app that is written in a language that supports multi-thread.

when two requests or more arrive this app (at the same time), what does the app actually do, does it asks the server to run itself in a different thread?,(the number of threads is the number of the requests), or does it asks the server to run a part of the code from itself to manage the requests?, in the first situation if it runs the entire app in a different thread, are not they using the same port (at the same time) which is a CONST in the code, must not be a conflict to use the same port? .
hope you clarify the idea for me and thanks.

Comment: First things first, the behaviour of the application is dependent of its code which is unknown here. Whether threads are native threads or not is dependent of the browser which is also unknown here. The way the server behave is dependent of its code which is also unknown... Besides, interpreted languages like Python/R have a standard implementation that makes use of a global lock preventing any true multi-threading (at least in most cases). Thus the target language also matters. You need to add these details so we can actually answer the question. Otherwise, the answer is: it depends!